# Detect intent from unstructured data for Watson Conversation

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

How do you discover intents that can be used in Watson Conversation from support desk chat history?  Is there an example or paper out there that discusses best practices on this topic?

Comment: This should help you to some extent http://stackoverflow.com/a/39815785/6785877